# Postgres fails to start, pg_clog fails

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql

Recently one of the machines running Postgres ran out of disk space. After deleting some trashes (**not related** in any way to postgres!) I've rebooted the system, and - after that - Postgres refuses to start.
The log below:

```
LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
LOG:  record with zero length at 4/E7000288
LOG:  redo is not required
FATAL:  could not access status of transaction 2718420992
DETAIL:  Could not open file "pg_clog/0A20": No such file or directory.
LOG:  startup process (PID 11496) exited with exit code 1
```

I've googled a bit and all I've found is to create a zero-filled 256k file `pg_clog/0A20`. Unfortunately, this doesn't solve the problem as now it complains on following:

```
2013-09-18 10:29:58 CEST FATAL:  could not access status of transaction 2718420992
2013-09-18 10:29:58 CEST DETAIL:  Could not open file "pg_clog/0A20": No such file or directory.
```

The **most important** thing for me is to **get it running** again as soon as possible, I do not care about losing the unfinished transactions however I can't afford losing the archive data (i.e. the data collected before the system ran out of disk space).

Comment: The second log message is not the real message, is just some detail. Could you show the messages above that one?

Comment: @MatheusOl thats because the rest of log messages are the same as previously - anyway I've updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

`pg_resetxlog` is made for situations like this.  Please read its man page, it contains important details.

Comment: I've tried running it with -f option, it said "Transaction log reset" but the startup error is still the same